# Difference between simulator and my analysis

Tags: diodes, analog, multisim, accuracy

I have this circuit:

[image]

I have done circuit analysis and found the total current to be 21mA.

Here is what I have done:

[image]

But when I run the same circuit in multisim it shows me 20.6mA.What could it be?Am I wrong?

This is the output of the multimeter XXM1

[image]

I know I have done 2 similar questions but I cannot find the error here? And here is my set of equations run on the system equation solver

[image]

And I know how to change and have changed the model of each virtual diode :

[image]

Model of D1 diode.

x = VA

y = I1

z = I2

The resistance of each diode is 0 and the junction potential for D1 is 0.7V , for D2 is 0.3V
I use **virtual** diodes

Comment: If you'd have done some research into silicon diodes you would have found that they have a variable forward conduction voltage and it is only fixed at 0.7 volts as an approximation. Ditto but lower for Germanium diodes.

Comment: Please use the built-in image uploader, don't make people chase other sites for pictures.

Comment: Excuse me, but the numeric value of R2 varies. In circuit diagram it looks like 300 Ohm and in some equations 100 Ohm. Or maybe I need eyeglasses.

Comment: I honestly hope it wasn't you that downvoted based on this reason. That would imply your mindset is "I know better", and that will make you unable to learn anything. And if you gathered downvotes, it's because you reject what people are telling you, which brings the question: why bother asking in the first place? Not to mention you are wasting people's time that is freely and voluntary given. Please correct your thinking, it will only help you in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even those "ideal diodes" have a dynamic resistance and, thus, a variable voltage drop. It's up to you to see how by running a simple `.OP` or `.DC` with one of those diodes. You'll see that you need to use the parameters defined in the `.model` if you want precise numbers. Otherwise, 20.6 mA vs 21 mA is good enough, given the circumstances. I'd call it success at this point. But, again, if you want accuracy then you can't rely on assumptions.

---

You don't seem to understand that it doesn't matter how it's called or labeled, a diode in a simulator obeys some dynamic law that makes its voltage drop to differ as a function of the current through it.

Here is the proof, if you're so reluctant to do it yourself:

[image: test]

`I1` is a current source with a ramp from 0 to 1 A, over 1 sec (`I(I2)`). Place that across your "virtual diode". You'll see a curve much like `V(x)`, which is the voltage across the diode. That's because what you're showing is, most probably, a standard Berkeley diode who follows the same equation you'll see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation):

$$\begin{align}
I&=I_S\Bigl(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{V_D}{nV_T}}-1\Bigr)\tag{1} \\
&\Rightarrow \\
V_D&=\ln{\Biggl(\dfrac{I}{I_S}+1\Biggr)nV_T}
\end{align}$$

Which tells you that `V(x)` is very much a logarithmic curve, or what you see. This is verified by `V(y)`, which is a behavioural source with the same expression, except \$V_T\$ is approximated to be `26 mV` (as opposed to some `25.85 mV`).

This is why I told you to test the diode; `.OP`, `.DC`, `.TRAN`, it doesn't matter, as long as you *test* it to see that what people are telling you is not a lie. Testing is up to *you*. You are supposed to make sure that the models you are using are behaving *as expected*. And then you'll realize your stubbornness in thinking that, simply because it's labled as a "virtual diode", it doesn't mean that it doesn't have a dynamic characteristic.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok i test it and if it shows dynamic behavior I will upvote this answer.

Comment: @a concerned citizen thanks a lot!.